# Creating jupyter notebook with Python code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, nbformat

I am creating a `jupyter notebook` programatically with Python. Using the `nbformat` library.

Once I create the file:

```py
fname = f'{filename}.ipynb'

with open(fname, 'w') as notebook:
   nbf.write(nb, notebook)
```

I open the file with Jupyter Lab and get the following error in the terminal console:

```
Fatal Python error: init_import_size: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sota/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 580, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/sota/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 567, in main
    known_paths = addsitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/Users/sota/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 350, in addsitepackages
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
  File "/Users/sota/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 208, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "/Users/sota/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
    exec(line)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/sota/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/importlib/util.py", line 14, in <module>
    from contextlib import contextmanager
  File "/Users/sota/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 5, in <module>
    from collections import deque
  File "/Users/sota/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/collections/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    import heapq as _heapq
  File "/Users/sota/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/heapq.py", line 581, in <module>
    from _heapq import *
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I have been researching a lot, but I don't get to find the error... some guidance on why this is happening?

PD: the only solution I've found so far is openinig the `notebook` with `vscode` and somehow, the notebook gets fixed.

Comment: Try to specify version in according a documentation:

https://nbformat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Comment: You need to use ```notebook``` at ```nbf.write()```

Answer (score 0):

It was actually a very newbie error. I had written the names of the folders with accented characters. Therefore, `Jupyter Lab` couldn't recognize correctly the files.